# Gson deserialization with changing field types

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I get a JSON which has the following structure:

```
{"field1": "string",
"field2": false,
"a": {
    "b": {
        "listString": []
    },
    "c": {
        "listString": [],
        "s": "string"
    },
    "parent": {
        "childA": {
            "listString": ["string", "string"]
        },
        "s": "string"
    },
    "parent2": {
        "listString": ["string", "string"],
        "s": "string"
    }
},
"field3": ["s", "s"]
}
```

I'm facing problems with the `parent` (and `parent2`) because the format of those fields can change. While the format of the complex objects `b` and `c` stays the same. For example, I can get `parent` (the same holds for `parent2`) in this way:

```
{"parent": {
    "childA":{
        "listString": ["ssssa", "a"]
         },
     "s": "string"
}}
```

or

```
{"parent": {
    "listString": ["ssssa", "a"],
    "s": "string"
}}
```

Moreover, `childA` field (if exists) can have different names, it can be `childB` or `childC`

I created java classes for the complex objects:

```
public class MyPojo{
  private String[] field1;
  private String field2;
  private A a;
  private String field3;...}

public class A{
  private B b;
  private C c;
  private Parent parent;
  private Parent2 parent2;..}

public class Parent{
  private String s;
  private ChildA childA;...}...
```

How can I deserialize something like this with Gson if the `parent` and `parent2` objects have different formates?

Comment: is childA, childB and childC are the only options? or it can be anything with a child* prefix? for example childXX?

Comment: To be more precise, childA, childB and childC (if exist) should be AND, OR, NOT. And these are the only item names that can occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the parent class:

```
public class Parent {
Map<String, JsonElement> parent = null;

public Map<String, JsonElement> getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Map<String, JsonElement> parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

}
```

This is the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String input = "{\"parent\": {\"s\": \"string\",\"childA\":{\"listString\": [\"ssssa\", \"a\"]}}}";
    Gson gsonInstance = null;

    gsonInstance = new GsonBuilder().create();

    Parent p = gsonInstance.fromJson(input, Parent.class);

    Map<String, JsonElement> parentMap = p.getParent();
    Set<String> keyMap = parentMap.keySet();

    Iterator<String> iter = keyMap.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String name = iter.next();
        if(name.matches("child(.*)")){
            System.out.println(parentMap.get(name));
            // do your logic
        }
        if (keyMap.contains("listString")){
            List<String> listString = getListString(parentMap.get("listString"));
            System.out.println(listString.toString());
        }
    }

}

public static List<String> getListString(JsonElement list){
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
    List<String> listString = new Gson().fromJson(list, listType);
    return listString;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! It helps and works well for this example! 
However, my JSON is more complex and the **parent** field is just one part of it. Is it possible to create a custom deserializer which will, based on the values present in the map (so either ("childA" object and "s" string) or ("listString" array and "s" string)), convert all properties to appropriate Parent Java **object**?

Comment: I think you should mention it in the question. If you need something more generic answer for a complex class you may refer to a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226024/gson-with-several-known-classes/38321215#38321215